# Given a giturl,how to retrieve all the projects names present in that link?

Tags: github-api, gitpython

Suppose given any GitHub url for example https://github.com/github, I want to retrieve or list out all the repository names present under that url with language as java.
For example given the above link 
My output should be the all repository names with language java.

Comment: Are you able to provide more details about how the file contents are formatted? It's hard to provide any guidance here based only on the information provided...

Comment: @BrendanForster For example given this github repository link: https://github.com/github I need to get all the repositories name present in this url with language java

Comment: `github.com/github` is a link to the `github` organization on GitHub, but this does help me understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the user/organization on GitHub and want to query for repositories that are detected as a specific language, you can use the [Search Repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) API.

The key part of this is the `q` querystring parameter, and the documentation will help you to understand what's possible:

- [Constructing a search query](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#constructing-a-search-query)
- [Searching for repositories](https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-for-repositories)

This example shows how to look for Ruby repositories under the `github` organization:

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:github+language:ruby
```

This will return a JSON payload with the repositories that match:

```
{
  "total_count": 55,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    {
      // repository details
    },
    {
      // repository details
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```